# Inconsistent gigabit LAN speeds

Tags: gigabit-ethernet

I have two Windows 10 machines connected to my LAN. I have a gigabit unmanaged switch as the hub for my LAN. I looked around online and found Disabling "TCP Auto-Tuning" which didn't help. I then tried Disabling "Large Send Offload (LSO)" in my Network adapter, for both IPv4 and IPv6. It started out when transferring movies at around 56 MB/s and then went back down to the normal 13 MB/s speeds of which I am, used to.

I have gigabit NIC's on both computers, CAT 5e and CAT 6 cables, gigabit switches and ports on all my routers. What else am I missing? Could it be a damaged ethernet cable or connector?

```
./iperf3.exe -c 192.168.1.201                                                          
Connecting to host 192.168.1.201, port 5201                                                                             
[  4] local 192.168.1.102 port 2846 connected to 192.168.1.201 port 5201                                                
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth                                                                         
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  66.9 MBytes   561 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  66.9 MBytes   561 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  49.5 MBytes   415 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  52.0 MBytes   436 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  67.9 MBytes   569 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  66.0 MBytes   554 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  67.4 MBytes   565 Mbits/sec                                                                     
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  62.2 MBytes   522 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  68.9 MBytes   578 Mbits/sec                                                                    
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  68.9 MBytes   577 Mbits/sec                                                                    
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -                                                                       
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth                                                                         
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   636 MBytes   534 Mbits/sec                  sender                                            
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   636 MBytes   534 Mbits/sec                receiver
```

Comment: "Transferring movies" sounds like you're actually testing the source/destination storage speed, not the network speed. Can you install and run [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php) and provide the results?

Comment: 0.00-1.00   sec  66.9 MBytes   561 Mbits/sec

Comment: Does it continue running at the same speed? (And are both PCs connected directly to this switch? Honestly I would expect at least ~950 Mbps.)

Comment: That's what I expected as well. When I completed the disabling of the Large Send Offload (LSO) on both computers I saw for the very first time my LAN speed jump to 55 MB/s then after a few seconds it dropped down to 13 MB/s and stayed that way for the rest of the transfer. My Windows 10 computer is connected to a brand new desktop gigabit switch, which is then connected to a Netgear ORBI router (one ethernet port) and then a CAT 5e cable connects to the two to a gigabit unmanaged switch. The switch is connected to my Plex Media Server with a CAT 6 cable. Both have gigabit NIC cards.

Comment: Well, it sure sounds like 13 MB/s is just your target disk's write speed... But how exactly is the ORBI conencted to 2 gigabit switches if it has only one ethernet port?

Comment: The ORBI is connected to a 5 port TP-Link Gigabit desktop switch and my upstairs computer and printer is directly connected to this switch. I can eliminate the desktop switch and try again?

Comment: Are both computers on the same subnet? If so, traffic should't be going through the router _at all_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102205/discussion-between-kimosabe2016-and-grawity).

Comment: As traffic passes more than one network cards/router/switch, you might have [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) incompatibilities which fragment packages.

Comment: The speed being okay for a while and then dropping down to what are essentially 100Mbps speeds could be related to a bad or marginal network cable. It can just about work at gigabit, but multiple errors forces the PHYs to renegotiate at 100Mbps and drop the gigabit pairs for reliability. Have you tried replacing the cables?